# compute column without using window function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables as below :

Table 1 :

```
+-------+----------+-------+----------+----------+----------+------+
|pid    |ite       |zid    |   date   |usales    |csales    |p     |
+-------+----------+-------+----------+----------+----------+------+
|     p1|       it1|     z1|2016-11-21|       0.1|         1|     0|
|     p1|       it1|     z1|2016-12-05|       0.1|         1|     0|
|     p1|       it1|     z1|2017-01-05|       0.1|         1|     0|
|     p2|       it2|     z2|2016-11-28|       0.1|         5|     4|
|     p2|       it2|     z2|2016-12-12|       0.1|         3|     2|
|     p1|       it2|     z1|2016-11-14|       0.1|         2|     1|
|     p1|       it3|     z1|2016-11-21|       0.1|        10|     9|
|     p1|       it3|     z1|2016-12-05|       0.1|        10|     9|
+-------+----------+-------+----------+----------+----------+------+
```

Table 2 :

```
+------------+----------+--------+----------+----------+
|z_id        |p_id      |rate    |start_date|  End_Date  |
+------------+----------+--------+----------+----------+
|          z1|       it1|      25|2016-01-01|2016-06-01|
|          z1|       it1|   25.75|2016-01-01|      null|
|          z1|       it2|      25|2016-01-01|2017-03-01|
|          z1|       it2|   32.75|2017-01-01|      null|
+------------+----------+--------+----------+----------+
```

and I need the result table on the basis of join condition Table1.zid = Table2.z_id and Table1.ite = Table2.p_id,with following conditions:

```
 * if "week" column of first table is exist between "start_date" and "End_date" of second table then need to compute column "r" in result table as "Table1.usales * Table2.rate"

 * if "week" column of first table is NOT exist between "start_date" and "End_date" of second table then value of columnn "r" in result table is 0


 * if "week" column of first table is exist between "start_date" and "End_date" of second table  and "End_date" is null then need to compute column "r" in result table as "Table1.usales * Table2.rate"

*  if "ite" and "zid" of "Table1" is not present in second table then value of columnn "r" in result table is 0
```

OutPut Table :

```
+-------+----------+-------+----------+----------+----------+------+------+
|pid    |ite       |zid    |   date   |usales    |csales    |p     |r     |
+-------+----------+-------+----------+----------+----------+------+------+
|     p1|       it1|     z1|2016-11-21|       0.1|         1|     0|      |
|     p1|       it1|     z1|2016-12-05|       0.1|         1|     0|      |
|     p1|       it1|     z1|2017-12-05|       0.1|         1|     0|      |
|     p2|       it2|     z2|2016-11-28|       0.1|         5|     4|      |
|     p2|       it2|     z2|2016-12-12|       0.1|         3|     2|      |
|     p1|       it2|     z1|2016-11-14|       0.1|         2|     1|      |
|     p1|       it3|     z1|2016-11-21|       0.1|        10|     9|      |
|     p1|       it3|     z1|2016-12-05|       0.1|        10|     9|      |
+-------+----------+-------+----------+----------+----------+------+------+
```

I have tried this by making a left join between table 1 and table 2 and then dumping the result into "data" and doing partitioning as below :

```
"select * from (select *,Row_Number() over(partition by z_id,p_id,dateorder by r desc) as ID from data))a where ID=1
```

I am not sure how to do it using join and subquery as I need to avoid "WINDOW function".Can anyone please help

Comment: You ask for `CASE` expressions. Have you tried it? Show your code please.

Comment: I have tried ,Row_Number () as mentioned in description

Comment: How can i use case statement .Can you please help me ??

Comment: There is no week column in Table1. Do you mean Date?

Comment: i am sorry,yes it is date.I have edit it

Comment: Can you post also the results that you expect for this sample data?

Answer (score 0):

You need a `LEFT JOIN` of `Table1` to `Table2`:

```
select t1.*,
  case 
    when t1.date >= t2.start_date and t1.date <= coalesce(t2.end_date, t1.date) 
      then t1.usales * t2.rate
    else 0  
  end r
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2
on t2.z_id = t1.zid and t2.p_id = t1.ite
and (t1.date >= t2.start_date and t1.date <= coalesce(t2.end_date, t1.date))
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=98779de8cfaf73e71aef75ed611d3f25).
Results:

```
> pid | ite | zid | date       | usales | csales |  p | r     
> :-- | :-- | :-- | :--------- | :----- | -----: | -: | :-----
> p1  | it1 | z1  | 2016-11-21 | 0.10   |      1 |  0 | 2.5750
> p1  | it1 | z1  | 2016-12-05 | 0.10   |      1 |  0 | 2.5750
> p1  | it1 | z1  | 2017-01-05 | 0.10   |      1 |  0 | 2.5750
> p2  | it2 | z2  | 2016-11-28 | 0.10   |      5 |  4 | 0.0000
> p2  | it2 | z2  | 2016-12-12 | 0.10   |      3 |  2 | 0.0000
> p1  | it2 | z1  | 2016-11-14 | 0.10   |      2 |  1 | 2.5000
> p1  | it3 | z1  | 2016-11-21 | 0.10   |     10 |  9 | 0.0000
> p1  | it3 | z1  | 2016-12-05 | 0.10   |     10 |  9 | 0.0000
```